# Display contents of one folder in another

Tags: files, directory, symbolic-link

Is it possible to show all the files from one folder in another on Ubuntu? A bit like libraries on Windows?

More specifically I want files from a specific folder in my local Google drive folder to be shown on my desktop.

Maybe I could assign a custom function to a shortcut key which would loop through the Google Drive folder and recursively symlink the files onto the desktop. The only problem then would be having delete both the file and the symlink when the file is finished with.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to be what you are looking for:

[Can I make a folder display the contents of several other folders (like a Windows "Library" folder)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69758/can-i-make-a-folder-display-the-contents-of-several-other-folders-like-a-window)

Maybe you could take some of the answers to that question and use them to put the files you need on your desktop.